# How to restart browser in Cucumber + Selenium Webdriver + Page-Object?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I'm using Chrome and IE browsers. I need to restart the current browser and continue with the execution.
When I restart the browser, the current browser is closed and the new browser is launched  with the given url but throwing this error:

> no such session (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267521,platform=Windows NT 6.2 x86_64)

The script is:

```
$log.info("Due to exception '#{ex}' the current browser is being restarted")  
@browser = EHR::BrowserSettings.restart_browser
sleep 10
@browser.navigate.to(DESKTOP_APP_URL)
sleep 3
```

After this, the login script will be executed. How do I resolve the error?

Comment: first thing is selenium always start with new session once browser closed. so I think you will have to login again if you are restarting browser.

Comment: Actually Im able to launch the new browser with the url but it is not taking current @browser object value and thats why its throwing "no such error".

Comment: As I told you..once browser closed then session out..

Comment: I got it. the script for launching new browser should be placed in hooks.rb file. not its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
No actually the script is After block : 
if scenario.failed?
  $log.info("Due to exception the current browser is being restarted")
  @browser = nil
  @browser = EHR::BrowserSettings.restart_browser
  @browser.navigate.to(DESKTOP_APP_URL)
.....
this script is working (its relaunching the browser with the given URL).
Im trying to close the browser window in at_exit() hook and here im not able to get the @browser object value and hence could not close the browser.
I jst need to close it in the at_exit block. Is there any way to do it.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using watir-webdriver, but you could try:

```
@browser.close
@browser = Watir::Browser.new
```